# PHP security and unique naming conventions

Tags: php, security, naming-conventions

Is anything wrong with naming images uploaded by users (for example avatars) like that:

```
/user_id-username.jpg
```

Example:

```
/1-feont.jpg
```

All images has unique name (becouse user_id is primary key), but what about security? Has that any bad  influence? If has, what conventions should I do instead?

Comment: Don't know what limitations you've set on possible characters in the usernames. But not all characters are allowed in filenames. Why don't you use a convention like /avatar-user_id.jpg

Comment: As long the filename contains something unique which is not under the control of the user, then it should be fine. However, do you really want someone to upload "really_nasty_word_goes_here.jpg" and have that served up by your machine to one and all?

Comment: Hmm, nice point of view. ;) But let's have a look into gallery for example. Crawlers also find images, and it's a good source of visitors. Especially if image have name like wallpapers/jh8f8g_route_66.jpg. Of course, I have also title attribute. But in moderated site it's simlpy to delete some "nasty_image_title.jpg" or use censor and replace some strings.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the username is appropriately sanitized before using it as part of the filename. User id should be system generated so that should not cause any problems.

Comment: Of course, the file name contains only a-z and underscores. But the point is, if somebody undesirable has ids of records, can make some damage. Maybe conventions like random generated string is more secure?

Answer (score 1):

The name that you give the images is purely conventional. I do not think it is a security issue for revealing the usernames of your users. (If it is, then you better check your CMS right away!) However, if your website is not completely secure a hacker can make use of SQL injection to access your user data.

But the idea is really far-fetched. You can go ahead with using usernames. :-)

IMO, just name the images as `user-user_id.jpg` (Here, "user" being a normal string followed by the integer - user_id)

Answer (score 1):

Generally it is fine but some users may not like their name to be displayed and the user ID being a primary key could have vulnerability if your site isn't completely secure or if a PHP vulnerability is found in the future that is currently unknown.

For this sort of thing I tend to use the following code

```
$createName = date('YmdHis');
$fileType = '.jpg';
$imgName = $createName.$fileType;
```

This should give a string like 20110702155513.jpg - this is the full date and time the image was named and is unique.

If you really want to be safe then you can write a call back function that if there was a failure due to the file name not being unique (generally because there were 2 requests in the same second - unlikely but possible), then you can use a fall back adding the user ID in the middle of the string or use the fall back as your primary naming method, so for example

```
if($imgName == 'inuse'){
     $createName1 = date('Ym');
     $createName2 = date('dHis');
     $fileType = '.jpg';
     $imgName = $createName1.$userId.$createName2.$fileType;
}
```

This allows the user ID to be hidden but entirely unique.

**Edit - ** another option is to use the existing format and create an MD5 hash, the code would be something like

```
$user_id = 'user_id';
$username = 'username';
$fileType = '.jpg';
$fileName = md5($user_id).'-'.md5($username).$fileType;
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Yeah, that's fine. I know that method. But what can really hacker do having some id? I suppose... not much, when website tools don't give possibilities to create own names of files.

Comment: @Mr Sooul that depends on how you have developed your site, how long is a piece of string? E.g. If you use JavaScript for form validation and don't verify with PHP then I could bypass JS, using a primary key with a bit of smart cURL post information to your database that normally you wouldn't allow. As I said it's normally not a big problem but I still prefer going with a method that either completely hides the ID or doesn't use it at all. I can't comment on problems that haven't been discovered or created yet or what is possible on your specific site :-)

Comment: @Mr Sooul another issue could be if a cookie or session ID for login uses the key then I could potentially use that the forge the session and gain full control of the user account including making a password change. 1 option is to take the user ID and name option above and create an MD5 hash out of it for naming, will edit my answer now to include the code for the option

Comment: True, but we can use salts and then hash session id ;) But all in all I will update my avatars list. And now... what about gallery? photo_id isn't as useful as potentially user_id can be... So, in your opinion, can I consciously and safely use photo_id to provide unique naming?

Comment: I don't see any real issue there, I have a lower risk on galleries generally so I will allow more disclosure on them however, I still build a hidden field to any forms using any ID on the site, the field is given a value dynamically from the server, if it doesn't match when it is posted the script fails. It can tricky to write but I will generally use an existing numerical variable in the SESSION and manipulate that with an algorithm so the receiving script can assess if the key is correct or not, this really just avoids bot manipulation

Answer (score 1):

- Using the **date** as Ryan suggests fails when you have users that upload at the same time
- Using the **username** fails when users may change their username. "Fail" is a bit hard here, but you have to move the files around which is something that's not needed when using another solution
- Using the **id** solves all concurrency problems if the ID is an autogenerated auto-increment ID from your database. Opposed to *Kerrek SB*, I don't see a problem that this makes a connection between a unique identifier and an image on your file system. I mean it's unique and you can use it.

Using the ID also makes it easy for your users to find/link their image if you constantly use the ID publicly. If you on the other hand have only the user names in URLs - like `/profile/$username`, then I'd use the username in the image file name, too - to be consistent.

About security: If you sanitize the username, all is fine. Just make sure that it's unique, so people can't overwrite each other's names (which means that you need to use the same sanitation rules for usernames in database as you use for usernames in image file names).

Having the username as image name also makes it "easier" to find an image if you manually need to find one, but that probably happens not often enough to be of worth for you.

To summarize, I'd go with the ID.

Comment: Thanks for good response. Avatars were only example. And summarizing, I will rather generate random string for avatars. But when I need nice title (for example in gallery) I will rather use photo_id and sanitized title. I was only curios about what is worth user_id for uninvited visitors.

Answer (score 0):

there is no huge risk to naming files like the way you use in your first example but to make it more secure why don't you use something better like

```
    function Naming($username,$imagename)
{
    $uniq = time() ;
    $name  = $uniq.'-'.$username.'-'.$imagename ;
    return $name ;
}
```

i think its better to avoid using users ID's

Answer (score 0):

Unique user_id is enough, you don't need "username".
Problem isn't here, but in count of files (in one folder).
Split them by 1000 in folder (or by 100): take first, second and third symbols of ID string and put in separate dirs:

```
ID = 10524.jpg  
filename = 1/0/5/10524.jpg
```

If it's hard to write algorithm, you can try this function:

```
function getStorePath($filename, $base_dir)
{
    //file should have extension
    $ext_pos = strrpos($filename, '.');
    if ($ext_pos===false) return false;

    //extension will be sanitized (filtered actually)    
    $ext = preg_replace("|\W+|", "", substr($filename, $ext_pos+1));
    if (empty($ext)) return false;
    if (in_array($ext, array('php', 'shtml', 'cgi', 'inc', 'module', 'sh', 'sql', 'class'))) return false;

    //filename will be filtered    
    $filename = preg_replace("|\W+|", "", substr($filename, 0, $ext_pos));

    if (empty($filename)) $filename = mt_rand(100000, 999999).round(microtime(true)*1000000);

    //let's create path to the file.
    //we will take first 3 symbols of filename as names of folders    
    $d = realpath($base_dir).'/';

    //first symbol
    $d .= $filename[0].'/';
    if (!file_exists($d))
    {
        $md = mkdir($d, 0755);
        if ($md===false && !file_exists($d)) return false;
    }

    //second symbol
    if (isset($filename[1]))
    {
        $d .= $filename[1].'/';
        if (!file_exists($d))
        {
            $md = mkdir($d, 0755);
            if ($md===false && !file_exists($d)) return false;
        }
    }

    //and third symbol
    if (isset($filename[2]))
    {
        $d .= $filename[2].'/';
        if (!file_exists($d))
        {
            $md = mkdir($d, 0755);
            if ($md===false && !file_exists($d)) return false;
        }
    }

    if (!file_exists($d.$filename.'.'.$ext)) return $d.$filename.'.'.$ext;
    else return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I typically name my images a random string, then store it in the database attached to the uploaders id. You can also store other data about the image this way.

$filename = uniqid('', true) . '.jpg';

Image Table

id | user_id | filename | etc

Comment: this way if you ever decide to store more than one image per user, you don't have to change everything around.

Answer (score 0):

Just my own two cents. 
If you are gonna add more avatars for users to choose from, you're better off using a function like uniqid() instead of the user of. Else, you can do that all you like.

I use an MD5 hash of the userid and time() though. Just a matter of preference.